# Getting error in WordPress Illegal string offset

Tags: php, wordpress

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'user_login' in /home/.../wp-includes/user.php on line 83
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'user_password' in /home/.../wp-includes/user.php on line 83
```

Here the code:-

```
add_filter('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_cookie', 30, 3);

$user = wp_authenticate($credentials['user_login'], $credentials['user_password']);

if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
    if ( $user->get_error_codes() == array('empty_username', 'empty_password') ) {
        $user = new WP_Error('', '');
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `$credentials` is not that array. Show `var_dump($credentials);`

The error Illegal string offset 'whatever' in... generally means: you're trying to use a string as a full array.

That is actually possible since strings are able to be treated as arrays of single characters in PHP. So you're thinking the $var is an array with a key, but it's just a string with standard numeric keys

Comment: in my case this was the solution, `$credentials` was null so I added this check at the beginning `if ( $credentials == null) $credentials = array();`

Answer (score 0):

- Try adding following lines before $ user

  ```
       if(isset($_POST)){                                         
           $credentials = array(                               
              'user_login' => isset($_POST['log']) ? $_POST['log'] : '',
              'user_password' => isset($_POST['pwd']) ? $_POST['pwd'] :'',                  
          );                                                              
       }
  ```

Comment: after adding this code, whenever I login in wp-admin it open main site instead of dashboard.

Comment: Is your problem solved ? your dashboard working or not?

Comment: Can you please tell me the wordpress version you are using?

Comment: WordPress Version 4.5.2

Comment: I have downloaded wordpress version 4.5.2 i can't  find the issue but i think it must be related to php version you are using try yoursite.com/readme.html there you can find the system requirements it say you must have at least php version of 5.2.4 you can also check the Recommendations.